# Filter and Array formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[image]

I want to sort my data in order of the values of the members, but the groups should not be scattered.

For this, I wrote a formula to create a group min value.
However, you must populate the formula whenever groups and members are added.
I first tried `= ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(FILTER(I34:I41, G34:G41 = G34:G41)))`, but it seemed that `FILTER` didn't work with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

I hope that the value of the remaining cells will be automatically updated with the formula of one cell.
Is there a way to achieve this?
(First of all, I'm trying to figure out how to use formulas without apps scripts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter function does not work with arrayformula
Min function does not either. If you put an array inside Min function it returns the single smallest value.

But I have a solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(B4:B11, query(B3:D,"select B, min(D) where B is not null group by B label B '', min(D) ''",1),2,0))
```

[image]

First you build a table with minimum values using query function.

It returns:

1 | 1

2 | 10

3 | 4

Then you use vlookup formula to get a second column of freshly made table and you go with this using column B as a key.

Here is my solution in a spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VoM6ZRV0O3NUiqggGqN49kdDuBinfo6hQDiF8uNhKKY/copy